# How to use mfpic on Overleaf?

Tags: diagrams, overleaf

I would like to use `mfpic` to generate an image with Overleaf, but I am not even sure this is possible. I am not very familiar with all of this but someone sent some part of mfpic code for my report and I would like to print it. From the tutorial [here](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/mfpic/doc/mfpguide.pdf), after I have written the code below, apparently I am supposed to run a command "pdflatex first" but I don't know how exactly or where I am supposed to run it so I am stuck. The only output I get is a blank square with `#1` on the bottom left corner and no other files are made.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\opengraphsfile{myfigs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\begin{center}
\mfpicunit 1mm
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-10}{50}{-5}{45}
\draw\shade\polygon{(10,40),(30,30),(40,10)} \rect{(0,0),(30,30)}
\lines{(0,30),(10,40),(40,40),(40,10),(30,0)}
\lines{(30,30),(40,40)} \dashed\lines{(0,0),(10,10),(40,10)}
\dashed\lines{(10,10),(10,40)} \arrow\lines{(0,0),(27,27)}
\tlabel[tr](0,0){\tiny{(000)}} \tlabel[tl](30,0){\tiny{(100)}}
\tlabel[tl](40,10){\tiny{(101)}} \tlabel[bl](11,11){\tiny{(001)}}
\tlabel[cr](0,30){\tiny{(010)}} \tlabel[tl](31,31){\tiny{(110)}}
\tlabel[cl](41,40){\tiny{(111)}} \tlabel[br](10,40){\tiny{(011)}}
\end{mfpic}
\caption{Caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Tom from Overleaf Support here. I would like to check this, however, the code you provided seems not to compile _at all_. Can you please edit the question to include a full-compatible [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/11002) (including `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and all other stuff) that shows the issue?

Comment: Hey,  I forgot 1 line of code and the \begin and \end {document}. It is edited and now the code compiles and outputs  a white square with the #1 on the corner.

Comment: You are missing the `metapost` part... in your log file it will say `Mfpic: No file myfigs.1.

Mfpic: Initializing myfigs.mp.
Mfpic: Don't forget to process myfigs.mp!
Mfpic: Apply metapost to myfigs.mp.
Mfpic: Then reprocess this file`

Answer (score 2):

Overleaf [has a `latexmkrc` rule](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F) that can run `metapost`; but `mfpic` doesn't output any log messages that lets `latexmk` know it needs to apply that rule. Adding `\typeout{No file myfigs.1.}` in your `.tex` file will help trigger the `latexmkrc` rule to run `metapost`.

[image: example working mfpic on Overleaf]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the attentive team from Overleaf will comment but I do not think you can do the two pass (latex + mpost) compilation needed to use `mfpic`. I would strongly recommend that you use Metapost directly via the `mplib` option, which does work well on Overleaf, providing you choose `LuaLatex` as the compiler (menu, top left).

As for what you are trying to draw, MP is not the best tool for 3D diagrams, but if you can manage with simple [isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) instead of proper perspective, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

numeric elevation, rotation, se, ce, sr, cr, unit_size;
elevation = 18; 
rotation = -12;
se = sind(elevation);
ce = cosd(elevation);
sr = sind(rotation);
cr = cosd(rotation);
unit_size = 89;

def p(expr x, y, z) = (x * cr - z * sr, y * ce + x * se * sr + z * se * cr) scaled unit_size enddef;

beginfig(1);

    drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 1/2);
    draw p(0,0,0) -- p(0,0,1) -- p(0,1,1);
    draw p(0,0,1) -- p(1,0,1);

    drawoptions();
    path t; t = p(0,1,1) -- p(1,0,1) -- p(1,1,0) -- cycle;
    fill t withcolor 7/8; draw t;
    
    draw p(0,0,0) -- p(1,0,0) -- p(1,1,0) -- p(0,1,0) -- cycle;
    draw p(0,1,0) -- p(0,1,1) -- p(1,1,1) -- p(1,0,1) -- p(1,0,0);
    draw p(1,1,0) -- p(1,1,1);

    interim ahangle := 30;
    drawarrow p(0,0,0) -- 2/3[point 2 of t, point 1/2 of t];

    label.llft("$\scriptstyle (000)$", p(0,0,0));
    label.lrt ("$\scriptstyle (100)$", p(1,0,0));
    label.lrt ("$\scriptstyle (101)$", p(1,0,1));
    % etc

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

which will compile with `lualatex` (on Overleaf) to produce:

[image]